# merge multiple tsv column-wise

Tags: r, bash

I have multiple tsv files representing different samples with data from measurements. Now I want to merge the files column-wise (by the independent variable) into one file, where I have each sample as a column. I already tried R with

```
temp = list.files(pattern = "*.tsv)
list2env(
     lapply(setNames(temp, make.names(gsub("*.tsv$", "", temp))), 
            read_tsv), envir = .GlobalEnv)
data_list = list(X1, X2)
merged = list(data_list) %>% reduce(full_join, by ="ind_var")
```

However, by doing so sample1.tsv and sample2.tsv will be a data.frame called X1 and X2 and I also need to list them all in `data_list = list()` which is really time consuming having hundreds of samples. Also, the data.frame merged will have colnames like count.x and count.y instead of sample1 and sample2.

My data structure:

```
head sample1.tsv
```

| ind_var | count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |

```
head samle 2.tsv
```

| ind_var | count |
| --- | --- |
| D | 1 |
| E | 2 |
| F | 3 |
| A | 2 |

desired output:

```
head merged_list.tsv
```

| ind_var | sample1 | sample2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 0 |
| C | 3 | 0 |
| D | 0 | 1 |
| E | 0 | 2 |
| F | 0 | 3 |

[here is what I get when I read_tsv(sample8)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmhcS.jpg)

Comment: Sample2 has 2 rows with ind_var E. Why only the first one is appended to the merged_list?

Comment: Oh, that's a typo. Should be F

Answer (score 0):

Is this a valid workaround?

```
# Samples:
sample1 = data.frame(ind_var = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
                     count = c(1, 2, 3))
sample2 = data.frame(ind_var = c('D', 'E', 'F', 'A'),
                     count = c(1, 2, 3, 2))

# Adding samples to the list
lst <- list(sample1, sample2)


# Renaming second column in each sample in the list to 'sample1', 'sample2', etc.
for (i in 1:length(lst)) {
  colnames(lst[[i]])[2] <- paste0('sample', i)
}

# Full join all samples in the list
merged_list <- lst %>% reduce(full_join, by = "ind_var", na)

#Put 0 instead of NAs
merged_list[is.na(merged_list)] <- 0

# Output
merged_list
  ind_var sample1 sample2
1       A        1        2
2       B        2        0
3       C        3        0
4       D        0        1
5       E        0        2
6       F        0        3
```

Comment: You can read all .tsv files and save them as dataframes in the list.

Comment: With this approach the samples are named as ascending numbers, but I have a different structure. When I read in the the files like in my command above, the sample order is:
`temp "sample10.txt" "sample12.txt" "sample13.txt" "sample14.txt" "sample15.txt" "sample17.txt" "sample18.txt" "sample19.txt" "sample20.txt"` ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `tidyverse` approach -

```
library(tidyverse)

temp = list.files(pattern = "*.tsv")

merged  <- map(temp, ~read_tsv(.x) %>% 
                 rename_with(~tools::file_path_sans_ext(.x), 2) %>%
                 mutate(across(.fns = as.character))) %>%
  reduce(full_join, by = 'ind_var') %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:

Column specification 
cols(
  Family = col_character(),
  Count = col_double()
)


── Column specification 
cols(
  Family = col_character(),
  Count = col_character()
)

Error: Assigned data `values` must be compatible with existing data.
ℹ Error occurred for column `Count.y.y.y`.
x Can't convert <double> to <character>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: I guess the `rename_with()` is not working. When try the different pipe levels I do not see any differences between `merged` before and after the rename command.

Comment: I just tried your command with the reduced example dataset provided above. Here, I also have a problem with the rename function, as `merged` has columns `count.x` and `count.y` instead of `sample1` and `sample2`.
With the greater amount of samples in my original dataset, the columns are named count.x, count.y, count.xx, count,yy, count.xxx, count.yyy and so on

Comment: each tsv has two columns. Also when opening with libre office calc I have 2 columns

Comment: yep, that works as expected and gives the results shown in my initial post

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the data.frame produced by read_tsv()

Comment: Did you manage to figure what is waiving the issue here @shahronak47 ?

Comment: No, sorry. I don't know what's going on here.